# how long should it take for ntfsclone to complete?

Tags: windows-7, linux, backup, ntfs-3g

I am trying to backup a Windows 7 installation from a Kubuntu box.
The hard drive is a 320GB Toshiba directly connected to a SATA interface and has always wored well.

My initiall attempt was to use `ntfsclone` + `xz` as below:

```
ntfsclone --save-image -o - /dev/sdb3 | xz -9e -T8 > Win7-20170621.ntfsclone.xz
```

But when I reach the point of actually backing up the data, (message "Saving NTFS to image ...") it takes hours!

Then I thought I could blame `xz` and rearranged things to simply backup without any compression:

```
ntfsclone --save-image -o Win7-20170621.ntfsclone.xz /dev/sdb3
```

But no better luck. It still takes hours.

My box is a quite good i7-7700K with 16GB DDR4 RAM and Kubuntu 16.04 is running from a 240GB Kingston SSD.
Monitoring system resources I see average CPU usage is only about 15% (with 100% on a single core from time to time).
Used RAM is never above 3GB.

Disk usage from `sdb3` is about 2.5MB/s - that is quite below what `hdparm -Tt` shows for this drive. I even tried copying files and speed is a quite good 40 to 60MB/s.
The destination drive usage is very low. From time to time I see some spikes of 5MB/s or so.

Is it normal?
I see people across the internet stating that `ntfsclone` should take only a few minutes to complete.
What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `xz` seems [to be slow](https://www.rootusers.com/gzip-vs-bzip2-vs-xz-performance-comparison/) and 15% on your processor means a single-thread program is doing its maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @xenoid but, as I said, it is not xz fault. ntfsclone takes hours even alone - with no xz at all.

Comment: Forgot to mention, xz is being run with -T8, i.e. 8 threads. IT means that the single-thread program is ntfsclone, not xz.

Comment: That may be counter-productive if that makes it access the drive(s) non-sequentially . Is your process monitor showing any process in "disk sleep" mode? Btw, is the 320GB drive 5400 or 7200rpm? Btw `man xz` on my 16.04 Kubuntu says that multithreading isn't really implemented?

Comment: Hello @xenoid. I just tried a different hard drive as backup and the `ntfsclone` time was *only* half an hour to backup 65GB. This is strange that the first drive make this time to double. I haven't checked yet the drive rpms but, of notice, this first one is NTFS while the second is FAT32. I suspect it can be the problem... EDIT: I double-checked and I was wrong. both are NTFS :(

Comment: @xenoid, I need to pay more attention t the man page. I haven't noticed this "not implemented multithreading" from xz.